# Every metric space is paracompact (an elegant proof)

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation, well-orders, paracompactness

I'm studying a different proof to show that each metric space is paracompact in the book: *Singh, Tej Bahadur-Introduction to Topology*. It is a very elegant construction unlike the inductive method that seems more cumbersome to me. However there are three things that I could not understand:

(1) Why can some $E_{n, \alpha}$ be empty?

(2) How can I intuitively or geometrically see the sets $F_{n,\alpha}$ and $V_{n,\alpha}$?

(3) Why is it obtained that $F_{n,\alpha} \subset X - U_\beta $ or $F_{n,\beta} \subset X - U_\alpha$ in the last part of the proof?

I'm very interested in knowing a good argument for these questions since I have not been able to figure it out on my own after many attempts and I'm eager to know the answers. Any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are some definitions:

**Definition.**
Let $X$ be a topological space. A collection of sets $\{U_{\alpha}\} \subset X$ (not necessarily open or closed) is said to be locally finite if to each ${x \in X}$, there is a neighborhood ${U}$ of ${x}$ that intersects only finitely many of the ${U_{\alpha}}$

**Definition.**  Let ${\left\{U_{\alpha}\right\} }$ be a cover of a space ${X}$. Then a cover ${\left\{V_{\beta}\right\}}$ is called a refinement if each ${V_{\beta}}$ sits inside some ${U_{\alpha}}$

**Definition.** A Hausdorff space is paracompact if every open covering has a locally finite refinement.

Comment: The proof only shows that each family $\mathscr V_n=\{V_{n,\alpha}: \alpha\in A\}$ is locally finite for each fixed $n$. But $\mathscr V_n$ **is not a covering** for fixed $n$, only the union $\mathscr V=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \mathscr V_n$ is a covering. I doubt very much that $\mathscr V$ is locally finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For each $\alpha$, removing the points of $U_{\alpha}$ at distance $< 1/n$ from the complement of $U_{\alpha}$ leaves $E_{n,\alpha}$. Loosely, trim away an open strip of width $1/n$ around the boundary of $U_{\alpha}$. (It may help to note that the family $\{E_{n,\alpha}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an exhaustion of $U_{\alpha}$, i.e., the sets are nested and their union is $U_{\alpha}$.) The set $E_{n,\alpha}$ is empty if every point of $U_{\alpha}$ is at distance $< 1/n$ from the complement of $U_{\alpha}$. Qualitatively, the set $U_{\alpha}$ is "thin" in the sense of containing no closed ball of radius $1/n$.
2. Well-ordering of $A$ means the covering sets can be ordered so that there is a "first" set, and each set $U_{\alpha}$ has a successor (unless there is a "last" set). Now, think of $E_{n,\alpha}$ as a cookie, and pass $E_{n,\alpha}$ along the list of covering sets preceding $U_{\alpha}$, with each set $U_{\alpha'}$ ($\alpha' \prec \alpha$) taking a bite (subtracting $U_{\alpha'}$, i.e., intersecting with $X - U_{\alpha'}$). The set $F_{n,\alpha}$ is what remains; it contains points of $U_{\alpha}$ that are at distance $\geq 1/n$ from the complement of $U_{\alpha}$ *and* do not lie in $U_{\alpha'}$ for every $\alpha' \prec \alpha$.
   Place an open ball of radius $1/3n$ about each point this partially-eaten cookie $F_{n,\alpha}$; the union of these balls is $V_{n,\alpha}$.
3. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two distinct indices in $A$, one comes before the other, say $\alpha \prec \beta$ without loss of generality. By construction, the open set $U_{\alpha}$ took a bite out of $F_{n,\beta}$, so $U_{\alpha} \cap F_{n,\beta} = \varnothing$, i.e., $F_{n,\beta} \subset X - U_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. The last two points are now very clear to me, but I still don't understand point (1), i.e. why some $E_{n,\alpha}$ could be empty? I know that $E_{n,\alpha} = U_{\alpha}-\{x \in U_{\alpha} \colon d(x,X-U_\alpha)<1/n\}$ (removing the strip of width $1 /n$ as you said). You say that $E_{n,\alpha}$ is empty if for every $x \in U_{\alpha}$ we have $d(x, X- U_\alpha)< 1/n$ but by definition, $E_{n,\alpha} $ contains all those points in $U_\alpha$ such that $d(x, X-U_{\alpha}) \geq 1/n$, so I don't understand how what you say can happen.

Comment: I think that the only way for this to happen is for $E_{n,\alpha}$ to be contained in the strip $U_{\alpha} - E_{n,\alpha}$, but I don't see it possible. I'm almost certain that there is some error in my reasoning and perhaps due to a misinterpretation in the geometric sketch. Can you give me more details?

Comment: For example, if $X$ is a Euclidean space and $U_{\alpha}$ is a ball of radius $r$, then $E_{\alpha, n}$ is empty provided $r \leq 1/n$, namely for $1 \leq n \leq 1/r$. That is, _no_ point of the ball is at distance greater than $1/n$ from the complement of the ball. (IIRC, we're not saying $E_{\alpha,n}$ is empty for all $n$; that could only happen if the open set $U_{\alpha}$ is empty.)

Comment: Your example is very good, now I understand that part very well. On the other hand, I know that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}E_{n,\alpha} \subset U_{\alpha}$, but the other contention is not very clear to me. That is, I want to prove that $U_{\alpha} \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}E_{n,\alpha}$. I assumed by absurdity that there exists some $x \in U_\alpha$ such that $x \notin E_{n,\alpha}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but I have not obtained an absurdity. Intuitively it is clear, but I want to prove it by some mathematical argument.

Comment: I'm sure I should use the fact that $d(x ,X-U_\alpha) >0$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Because $U_{\alpha}$ is open, for each point $x$ in $U_{\alpha}$ there is an $r > 0$ such that the ball of radius $r$ about $x$ is contained in $U_{\alpha}$; it follows that $d(x, X - U_{\alpha}) \geq r$, and therefore that $x \in E_{\alpha, n}$ if $1/n < r$.